# Spellchecking developer documents?

Tags: spell-checking, hunspell

I am working on a project which spellchecks developer documented, e.g Readme files. The project uses Hunspell for spellchecking, but developer documents contain a lot of jargon which Hunspell thinks is misspelled.

My workaround so far has been to build my own custom dictionary to use alongside an English dictionary which contains jargon words, e.g git, repo, xml, url

I have not been able to find a decent word list of developer terms, does such a thing exist?

My question is this, is there an easier way?